# What grade of titanium are "memory titanium" glasses made of?

Tags: materials, metals

I've worked with [different grades of titanium](http://www.supraalloys.com/titanium-grades.php). Mostly with grade 5, and also grade 1 which is ductile.

I know that some glasses are made of titanium and are called "memory titanium", I guess because they bend back to their original shape?

My question is, which grade of titanium would that be?

Comment: regarding your first question, you guessed right.

Comment: When you state glasses, do mean frames for spectacles?

Comment: @fred Yes, frames for spectacles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those glasses are made out of Shape Memory Alloys (SMA), from which the most common ones include nickel, titanium, copper, zinc, or iron in their composition. I don't think the tag: **grade of titanium**, is applicable for SMAs even it they contain a high percentage of titanium.

As a functional materials, their properties and applications are so different that they have their own system. For example, one of the most recognizable brands of SMAs, Nitinol (nickel-titanium):

> ...offers different **grades of Nitinol**, which are distinguished by the
>   austenite start temperature of the ingot:
>
> - Nitinol #1 (superelastic) -35 to -10 °C
> - Nitinol #2 (superelastic) -45 to -15 °C
> - Nitinol #4 (superelastic) -10 to +10 °C
> - Nitinol #5 (shape memory) ≥ +85 °C
> - Nitinol #6 (shape memory) +35 to +85 °C
> - Nitinol #8 (shape memory) +10 to + 35 °C
> - Nitinol #9 (superelastic) ≥ +35 °C

From: https://cdn.thomasnet.com/ccp/00956637/229312.pdf

It is possible to tune the shape-memory and superelasticity properties of the alloy by modifying its composition. And speaking about the glasses (spectacles), you are more interested in the [superelasticity behavior](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4fQHgjgc3Y) of the material rather than in its [shape memory effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPrg8EZlD1E).

Answer (score 1):

Titanium used for frames is either 99% pure or, for memory frames 75% Titanium and 25% of nickel or copper.

You can read more here (the result of a google search) : https://www.zennioptical.com/blog/whats-so-terrific-about-titanium-frames/